# Multipart file and number of form parameters are not converting as ModelAttribute in Rest controller (Spring 4)

Tags: spring, forms, postman, multipart, modelattribute

I am using Chrome postman client for rest calls, here I am sending 15 form parameters like `fname`, `last name`.. so on, and also two files as file type.
I am submitting my request POST method, body type is form data selected  and  content type header  is empty.

In the server side, I am consume this as method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create"
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = {"multipart/form-data"},
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ResponseTO> create( @ModelAttribute RequestTO updateTripRequestTO, HttpServletRequest request);

public class RequestTO implements Serializable {
    private UUID id private Date createdate;
    private String createdby;
    private String updatedby;
    private Date updateddate;
    private String visibility;
    private String name;
    private MultipartFile tripimage;

public class RequestTO implements Serializable {
     private UUID id private Date createdate;
     private String createdby;
     private String updatedby;
     private Date updateddate;
     private String visibility;
     private String name;
     private MultipartFile tripimage;
```

( and Set and get Methods)

When I debug the TO, its giving comma separated values in TO.
If I give `fname` is `"Test"`, `lname "Ltest"` in the postman, when I debug the TO its coming `fname`  as `"Test,Test"`  and `lname` as `"Ltest,Ltest "` for all form fields. Can some suggest me why like this and any solution please.

Comment: can you provide RequestTO  class and your postman request

Comment: public class RequestTO implements Serializable {

 
 private UUID id

 private Date createdate;

 private String createdby;

 private String updatedby;

 private Date updateddate;

 private String visibility;

 private String name; 
 
       private MultipartFile tripimage;

Comment: public class RequestTO implements Serializable {

 
 private UUID id

 private Date createdate;

 private String createdby;

 private String updatedby;

 private Date updateddate;

 private String visibility;

 private String name; 
 
       private MultipartFile tripimage; and Set and get Methods

Comment: what is your postman request

Comment: Method : POST
url : http://localhost:/8080/context/plan?uid=123&token=cvu04730vs159i1dld1

Header : empty

body: form-data selected

fname  Test            text
lname  Ltest           text
Age    21              text 
image  ChoseeFile      File 
address  Address       Text
image1  Choosefile*(bg.jpg) File

It goes on like for 15 fields for text type data

Comment: do you use zuul proxy anywhere in your stack? Its causing double parameters in case of multipart requests.

Comment: i am not using zuul proxy,

Comment: can some one reply me please, i am struggling for this

Comment: @freakman: yes i am using zuul. Its here as it is:  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/941

Comment: With zuul you have to add /zuul somewhere in a path so it works with multipart requests correctly.. please make a comment here tomorrow here so I dont forgot.. i dont have this code at home